# .Net MAUI where to store api keys and connection strings?

Tags: c#, .net-maui

Fairly new to .Net MAUI and have not been able to find an answer in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/).

I am aware of the [Secure Storage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=android) and the [Preferences API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=android), but am wondering what is the proper way to store something like a connection string and keep it secure?  I read in other posts that secure storage and/or preferences should not be used for such things as connection strings and/or API keys.

If I include a connection string in an appsettings.json file and mark the file as an Embedded Resource, would that be considered secure?

For example, if an app is using a connection string to upload data to an AWS or Azure storage account, what would prevent a malicious third party from obtaining the connection string (and then use it to upload data to your storage account)?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who are you trying to keep the connection string secure from? If you are trying to keep it secure from the user, then there isn't anything that can do that. If you want to keep it secure from other users or third parties, then secure storage might be able to help.

Comment: Updated the question - I guess the only safe way is to implement an authentication scheme that prevents someone who might gain access to a connection string.

Comment: A client application should not have any credentials to do anything that the user of that application would not be able to do. You may need a system to protect the users credentials, and that is what secure storage is for, but for system credentials you need a server based authorization scheme.

Comment: @user1937198 - Thanks -- that make sense and explains why there is no issue with a connection string being "unsecured"  per se as authentication would occur on the server side.

Comment: Read about "tokens". The idea is that after initial authentication, a token is securely sent to device. The token ONLY works when sent back to server from the same device. Thus, is useless elsewhere, even if somehow captured. (I am not an expert on security, so my description may be only approximate.)

Comment: Probably the best resource I found was from [https://thedotnetshow.com/](https://thedotnetshow.com/) - See **Episode 24**, entitled "**Calling Secured APIs with MSAL Auth in MAUI**" - [The related YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8NRvakFW2M)
- [The related GitHub repo / code](https://github.com/carlfranklin/MsalAuthInMaui). Hope the above resources help others as well.